# Transiting Germany with current Corona restrictions

Tags: schengen, transit, germany, covid-19, quarantine

I am an Australian citizen however I hold a German Residence Permit (Type D Visa).

I am currently in the UK and would like to travel to Denmark via Hamburg (Germany).

My journey would look like this: fly from London to Hamburg then immediately take the train from Hamburg to Copenhagen.

I have tried to understand the current corona regulations in Germany but am getting mixed information.

The questions I need to confirm are:

1. Can I enter Germany with just a residence permit (type D visa)?
2. Can I take the train directly to Denmark from Hamburg without quarantining in Germany?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am under the impression that entry from the UK to Germany is rather problematic currently, due to the Delta Variant. That aside, since you're only transiting Germany, you wont be required to quarantine. As for the Denmark side of the business, I can't say anything.

Comment: Are you a resident of Germany (registered as a resident) or are you just a holder of a residence permit? If you are actually not a resident, being the holder of a residence permit is not sufficient to be allowed to enter when coming from the UK.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the pandemic is now over.